# DB2 Users on SAP

Tags: db2, sap-basis

I have three DB2 database accounts. I was wondering if it is possible to access SAP database using the DB2 database accounts like from the SAP GUI. I would also like to know if we can find the account status of the DB2 users (locked/unlocked) etc.

Comment: If by "access SAP" you mean access SAP tables, then yes. You can access them using DB accounts.

Comment: @Suncatcher : Thanks a lot. Can we know that status of these user accounts on DB2?

Comment: Use table [usr02](http://www.se80.co.uk/saptables/u/usr0/usr02.htm) as DB2Philipp kindly suggested, field `UFLAG`

Comment: @Suncatcher : USR02 will give me the status of accounts at SAP. I am looking for account status at the database level.

Comment: I cannot understand what is "account status at the database level"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the SAP application using the DB2 accounts.
SAP users are defined and the information is stored amongst others in the usr02 table.

The db2 user are defined on the OS or in the authentication tool used by the database.

You might access the SAP  data using the DB2 instance user depending on data access setup.